# Telegram bot that retrieves news articles based on user requests

Tags: java, beginner, natural-language-processing, telegram

This code is for a Telegram bot I created. Basically if the user types in `Whats the news`,`Whats the technology news`,`Whats going on in Syria`, `Whats happening in New York City`, etc it will retrieve 4 articles from google news related to the users query. This uses CoreNLP to analyze the sentence.

Just by the way I am only 14 years old and started learning Java a few months ago so I would be very appreciative of any help.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;



import java.util.Iterator;

//import javax.lang.model.element.Element;


import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.TelegramApiException;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.TelegramBotsApi;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.Message;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;

import edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger;

public class NewsBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {


    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static URL URLObj;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static URLConnection connect;

    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public boolean contains(String st1, String st2, String st3) {
        st1 = st1 == null ? "" : st1;
        st2 = st2 == null ? "" : st2;
        st3 = st3 == null ? "" : st3;

        return st1.toLowerCase().contains(st2.toLowerCase())
                && st1.toLowerCase().contains(st3.toLowerCase());
    }




    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (update.hasMessage()) {
            Message message = update.getMessage();

            if (message.hasText()) {


                SendMessage sendMessageRequest = new SendMessage();
                sendMessageRequest.setChatId(message.getChatId()
                        .toString());
                sendMessageRequest.enableMarkdown(true);

                ArrayList<String> nouns = new ArrayList<String>();

                // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                // Initialize the tagger
                MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger(
                        "taggers/english-left3words-distsim.tagger");

                // The sample string

                String sample1 = message.getText();

                // tokenize the sentence
                String delimeter2 = " ";
                // split the string using the delimeter and the parameter
                String[] words1 = sample1.split(delimeter2);
                System.out.println(words1);

                for (String word : words1) {
                    System.out.println(word);
                    // The tagged string
                    String tagged = tagger.tagString(word);

                    // Output the result
                    System.out.println(tagged);
                    if (tagger.tagString(word).contains("NNP")
                            || tagger.tagString(word).contains("NNS")
                            || tagger.tagString(word).contains("NN")
                            || tagger.tagString(word).contains("NNPS")
                            || tagger.tagString(word).contains("JJ")) {

                        if (tagged.contains("whats") || tagged.contains("news")
                                || tagged.contains("Whats")
                                || tagged.contains("News")) {

                        } else {
                            nouns.add(word);

                        }

                    }

                }

                // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                if (nouns.size() == 0) {

                    org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = null;
                    try {
                        doc = (org.jsoup.nodes.Document) Jsoup.connect(
                                "https://news.google.com/").get();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Elements el = doc.select("h2");

                    int i = 0;

                    for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element element : el) {


                        if (element.select("a").attr("href") != null) {
                            i++;

                            sendMessageRequest.setText(element.select(
                                    "[class=titletext]").text()
                                    + " - To read more "
                                    + "[click here]("
                                    + element.select("a").attr("href") + ")");

                            try {
                                sendMessage(sendMessageRequest);

                            } catch (TelegramApiException a) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                a.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            if (i > 5) {
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                } else if (nouns.size() == 1) {
                    System.out.println("Searching for " + nouns.get(0));

                    try {
                        System.out.println("Reading text...");

                        org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://news.google.com/news/feeds?cf=all&ned=us&hl=en&q=" + nouns.get(0) + "&output=rss").get();

                        Elements elements1 =  doc.select("title");
                        Elements elements2 =  doc.select("link"); 

                        Iterator<org.jsoup.nodes.Element> iter1 = elements1.iterator();
                        Iterator<org.jsoup.nodes.Element> iter2 = elements2.iterator();

                        int i2 = 0;

                        while (iter1.hasNext() && iter2.hasNext()) {

                            i2++;

                            Element element1 = (Element) iter1.next();

                            Element element2 = (Element) iter2.next();
                            if (element2.text().equals("http://news.google.com/news?hl=en&ned=us&q=" + nouns.get(0))) {

                            } else {
                                sendMessageRequest.setText(element1.text() + " - To read more " + "[click here](" + element2.text() + ")");
                                sendMessage(sendMessageRequest);
                            }

                            if (i2 > 5) {
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        System.out.print("failed");

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {                        
                    String compoundNoun = "";


                    for (int i = 0; i < nouns.size(); i++) {

                        String noun = nouns.get(i);

                        compoundNoun += noun + " ";

                    }

            System.out.println("Searching for " + compoundNoun);

                    try {
                        System.out.println("Reading text...");

                        org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://news.google.com/news/feeds?cf=all&ned=us&hl=en&q=" + compoundNoun + "&output=rss").get();

                        Elements elements1 =  doc.select("title");
                        Elements elements2 =  doc.select("link"); 

                        Iterator<org.jsoup.nodes.Element> iter1 = elements1.iterator();
                        Iterator<org.jsoup.nodes.Element> iter2 = elements2.iterator();

                        int i2 = 0;

                        while (iter1.hasNext() && iter2.hasNext()) {

                            i2++;

                            Element element1 = (Element) iter1.next();

                            Element element2 = (Element) iter2.next();
                            if (element2.toString().contains("http://news.google.com/news?hl=en&amp;ned=us&amp;q=")) {

                            } else {
                                sendMessageRequest.setText(element1.text() + " - To read more " + "[click here](" + element2.text() + ")");
                                sendMessage(sendMessageRequest);
                            }

                            if (i2 > 5) {
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        System.out.print("failed");

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return botConfig.BOT_TOKEN;
    }

}

class botConfig {
    public static final String BOT_USERNAME = "Stephaneaibot";
    public static final String BOT_TOKEN = "264738614:AAGzpvhSnDCWVSONBgNBtQa0kheZ_jGzIIM";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
        System.out.println("Compiled");
        try {
            telegramBotsApi.registerBot(new NewsBot());
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just at a very quick glance:

- You should really think twice about using the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation.  Warnings are usually a sign that something is not doing what you think it is, and rather than suppressing them, you should deal with them.
- You should avoid variable names such as `<something><number>` (i.e. `elements1`).  Your variable should tell me everything I need to know about it (i.e. `titleElement`).
- There are a few places where you are simply "swallowing exceptions" - i.e. you're printing the stack trace in the `catch` block, but otherwise doing nothing and letting the code continue.  This is likely to lead to a lot more exceptions coming from the first one.  You will need to think about whether you will want to return from the method, re-throw the exception, or find another way to assign the variables you're setting inside the `try`.